# how to create a constant file in the ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

What is the best/recommended way to set a global constant to be used across the entire app, like an API URL string?

I have the JSON format and want to set a global constant and use across the entire app as a static.
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`

`@Injectable()`
`export class Service {`
`item_data = [`
 `{ item_id:'1', item_image: "assets/img/bluesaphire.jpg",` `item_title:'Blue Saphire Stone' }`
 `];`

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple! Just follow these two steps -

1) Create an ***[Injectable](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable)*** class (eg. AppConstants) in a root directory (eg. src) with required properties

2) Import it in your component class constructor & use wherever needed

So, your *app.constants.ts* would be like -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
public class AppConstants {
    public item_data = [
        { item_id:'1', item_image: "assets/img/bluesaphire.jpg",  item_title:'Blue Saphire Stone' } 
    ];
}
```

And, use it as -

```
// here, config is a directory & app.constants is a ts file
import { AppConstants } from '../../config/app.constants';    // update your way

public class TestComponent {
    // dependency injection
    constructor(private constants: AppConstants) { }

    testMethod() {
        // using it here
        console.log(this.constants.item_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: will you eloborate like what to do in the (constant).ts file and all how to set and get the data of these in other .ts file..?

Comment: as i have used in config file used a `AppConstants.ts`,and in the `Item.ts` ->
`import { AppConstants } from '../../config/appconstants/appconstants';` error comes cannot find module..!

Comment: updated an answer again, ensure that you are importing it right as you named it

Comment: For your convenience, if you are unable to import `AppConstants` class correctly, just inject it first without importing & your IDE/ editor should suggest an import & then import it that way. It will import correctly.

Comment: imported as you said and i am coding in the sublime there is no other editor `cannot resolve all the parameters ItemPage: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).`

Answer (score 0):

Environment Variables can is a good way to handle this. See example:

https://medium.com/prototype-berlin/a-simple-way-to-use-environment-variables-in-ionic-3-12641dc55b55