# Angular N - what is the best practice of declaring a constant file?

Tags: angular, typescript

To declare a constant file, I first create it in the same tree level as the component where the constant is used `email.constants.ts` and like this:

```
export class EmailConstants {

  public static MAXIMUM_NUMBER = 10;
}
```

And I import it that way from the controller:

```
import { EmailConstants } from './emails.constants';
```

Is this practice good? I ask the question here because I can not find the answer in the official guide style

Comment: I would use Dependency Injection instead

Comment: I think you can get more opinions in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415446/5729813) is a solution using a separate file for constants, where you need to just take an instance of a class & access any constant

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I will do it like this:

```
export const MAXIMUM_NUMBER = 10;
```

and

```
import { MAXIMUM_NUMBER } from './emails.constants';
```

So only import what you use, not everything.

but if you still want to use everything, you can do it similarly as you have done, just change it a bit:

```
import * as EmailConstants from './emails.constants';
```

Then you can still use

```
EmailConstants.MAXIMUM_NUMBER
```

Comment: even you can use export const EmailConstants={  MAXIMUM_NUMBER:10, MINIMUN_NUMBER:1} and import {EmailConstants} from './configuration'

Comment: Correct @Eliseo

Answer (score 18):

> **It is a good practice to make a separate file for your constants**. Where, there could be multiple scenarios, in which ***I prefer/ recommend the Second one*** from the followings -

1) Export every constant & import as needed; if you don't have too many constants.

```
export const TEST = "testval";
export const TEST2 = "testval2";
```

Import as -

```
import { TEST, TEST2 } from './app.constants';
```

2) Create & export a single ***[Injectable](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable)*** class if you have too many constants & want a *hassle-free* import.

So, your *app.constants.ts* would be -

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConstants {
    public TEST = "testval";
    public TEST2 = "testval2";
}
```

Then, you could simply inject it in your required class like -

`constructor(private constants: AppConstants)` & use as - `constants.TEST`

3) You could also export an Object as -

```
export const constObj = {
    TEST: "testval",
    TEST2: "testval2"
};
```

And import it as -

`import { constObj } from './app.constants';` & use as - `constObj.TEST`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to avoid name collisions by "putting the file on the same tree level"?
If so, consider [Dependency Injection and Injection Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289264/what-is-in-angular-2-opaque-token-and-whats-the-point#41782168).