# How to create constant.ts file to declare global constants

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create(or command to create) constant.ts file to declare all global constants. That is to export all global constants

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create it manually. Literally create a file called constant.ts, then follow the advice given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54588783/17563685